# Messed up bash prompt, probably due to changes in bashrc

Tags: bash, shell, prompt

I wanted to change my bash prompt (like any nerd) and keep a custom name for it.

I have already come up with the code which works, but it has some problems. The code is

```
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
    PS1="[ \[\e[1;33m\]| Dragon Master | \[\e[1;36m\]\[\e[49m\] \W \[\e[0m\]]\e[0;37m ";
else
    PS1="\[\e[1;36m\][ \[\e[1;33m\]| Dragon Master | \W $\[\e[1;36m\]]\e[0;37m ";
fi
```

And it works fine (not totally),

[image: The demo]

But there is a problem with this, when the command gets bigger then one line, it does not go to the next line, but it starts overwriting in the same line. Like this,

[image: Another demo]

For reference, the command in the above picture is

```
x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1024 -enable-kvm -drive if=virtio,file=test.qcow2,cache=none -cdrom Fedora-Live-Desktop-x86_64-20-1.iso
```

Now, this weird line wrapping does not effect the command in any way. It works perfectly.

Suggestion Guys?

Comment: [This link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24358/how-do-i-get-long-command-lines-to-wrap-to-the-next-line) might help

Comment: @Tico, Thanks a lot brother. Issue resolved. :)

Comment: glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer in the link that was posted in the comments.

In `PS1` quote, every color set must have a `\\[` preceding it.

So, my code becomes,

```
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
    PS1="[ \\[\e[1;33m\]| Dragon Master | \\[\e[1;36m\]\\[\e[49m\] \W \\[\e[0m\]]\\[\e[0;37m\] ";
else
    PS1="\\[\e[1;36m\][ \\[\e[1;33m\]| Dragon Master | \W $\\[\e[1;36m\]]\\[\e[0;37m\] ";
fi
```

---

Taken from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24358/how-do-i-get-long-command-lines-to-wrap-to-the-next-line) answer.

Comment: To clarify: you don't need `\\[` in PS1.  What you need is `\[` at the beginning of any nonprinting characters, and `\]` at the end.  You use `\\[` within a double quotes string to get `\[` into PS1, because the double quoted string is interpolated and the first backslash is stripped.  You really should be using single quotes for this assignment: it would make it much cleaner.

Comment: In fact, glancing at your original code, it looks like all you need to do is change `"` to `'`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, Thanks. I just followed what I got from that link, and it worked. I will try this too.